# Angular app cache issue in loading nested view URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deployment, gulp, gulp-rev

I've been building my angular application using gulp. 
My **index.html** file will contain script and style file name with hash value append at the end.
This has been used to add *revision* to file names on every new build using [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev).
example:

```
 styles\app-6e83a19fec.css
 styles\vendor-c68ae715d2.css
 scripts\vendor-03197ad5c4.js
 scripts\app-ec22589d11.js
```

When I have loaded the base url after new packages are deployed, everything getting loaded from new package.

Sample Url: http://localhost/myapp/

But if we loaded the nested view url after new packages deployed, it still loading the ***old packages from the cache***.

Sample url: http://localhost/myapp/#/profile

I've tried adding the querystring to end of file name in **index.html**. And also its working properly, by loading new files if we load the base url of site.

If we load the nested view url, the ***old files are getting loaded***.

**example:**

```
 styles\app-6e83a19fec.css?v=1.1
 styles\vendor-c68ae715d2.css?v=1.1
 scripts\vendor-03197ad5c4.js?v=1.1
 scripts\app-ec22589d11.js?v=1.1
```

Comment: Are you using express? check the cache settings and change it accordingly.

Comment: No @MuliYulzary I'm not using right now

Comment: What server container are you using then?

Comment: I'm using node js + gulp server